# What are those arrowlike underwater structures for?

Tags: human-influence

Looks like it has something to do with fishing: [Google maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/9%C2%B032'00.9%22N+138%C2%B011'20.8%22E/@9.5339863,138.1891537,543m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d9.5335853!4d138.1890973)

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those are Yap Traditional Fish Weirs, according to [islandculture.info](http://www.islandculture.info/yaptraditionalfishweirs/index.htm)

> In 2008, Yap State Historic Preservation Office (YSHPO) commenced a
>   project to survey the fish weirs (aech) around the main island of Yap.
>   The aech is a stone/rock structure, usually in the shape of an arrow
>   (many have a shaft, some do not), that catch fish after they move
>   inside a catchment area at high tide and are trapped when the tide
>   goes out. It is thought 700-800 aech may be located around Yap's main
>   island which has a coastline of about 100 km in circumference.
>   [image: Yap traditional fish weirs]

Answer (score 9):

They look like stone fish traps or [weirs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing_weir). They are used by native poeple to catch fish on a large scale.  They can actually vary quite a bit by culture and can be quite large.  Here is a stone and wood one with the same shape

[image]